# Email Regex to allow special characters

Tags: regex, email-validation

How can I update the following regex to allow all special characters except "@" in the email handle.

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.+[a-z._-]+"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.+[a-z._-]+$
```

`[^@]+` will match 1 more of anything but `@`

Comment: whats the $ sign at the end?

Comment: `^` and `$` are anchors for asserting start and end positions.

Comment: Worked when I took about both anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Add special characters inside '[]'.

e.g. for adding support for colon

change
`"[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.+[a-z._-]+"`
to
`"[a-zA-Z0-9._-:]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.+[a-z._-]+"`

For more details check [valid email addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses) on wikipedia. Also going through the RFC [5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), [5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I find this a sensible way ..

```
 # http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address
 # ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$


 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ 
 @
 [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 )?
 (?:
      \. 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      (?:
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
           [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      )?
 )*
 $
```